# Error with BigDecimal

Tags: java

Some one can say me where is problem please ?

```
double interval;
         BigDecimal diff = BigDecimal.valueOf(17);
         int n=39;
         BigDecimal N = BigDecimal.valueOf(n);
         interval = diff.divide(N).doubleValue();//line26

         System.out.println(interval);
```

I have this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion; no exact representable decimal result.
    at java.math.BigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.java:1603)
    at newlogoot.class.main(class.java:26)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the result of the division is a non-terminating decimal number which can't be fully represented in a `BigDecimal` as is (as that would require an unlimited amount of memory).

Thus you need to restrict the number of its decimal digits using the two- (or three-) parameter version of [`BigDecimal.divide`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29), e.g.

```
     interval = diff.divide(N, 3, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN).doubleValue();//line26
```

(this rounds the result to 3 decimal digits.)